# Speech to Text in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, speech-recognition

Is there any API that could convert speech to text offline in Windows Phone 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin Marshall created an example that did just this using the beta version of the tools.

His blog post explaining this and a copy of his code cna be found at http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/05/12/windows-phone-7-prototype-001-speech-recognition-on-wp7/

Comment: Seems like this link is dead :(

Comment: Yes, it seems that link is no longer valid. For how to do speech-to-text on WP8 see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206958(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

No offline API available currently - and it looks like the future direction for this is online - see project Hawaii - http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hawaii/students/default.aspx (a version of this should be release in Feb 2011)

Answer (score 0):

Who'd have thought that 18 months later, Project Hawaii is still "intended for academic use only" -- i.e. not ready for primetime yet, in my book.  Here's a new "online" alternative: AT&T's Speech to Text API.

News article - http://www.research.att.com/articles/featured_stories/2012_07/201207_WATSON_API_announce.html?fbid=sM4gRrHiK7I

API Info - https://developer.att.com/developer/apiDetailPage.jsp?passedItemId=10700023

Only downside is it costs $99/year to utilize AT&T APIs.  Not a great solution if you give away your apps and don't make much ad revenue.